# How to set the output impedance of this circuit?

Tags: rf, analog, bjt, mixer

Assuming no biasing, would setting the Re to 300 Ω be the proper method of impedance matching?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDwVMc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I figure that at some point, a negative half-cycle of the mixed waveform would appear at the base. Since the emitter is in phase with the base of a BJT, conventional current would flow from ground--> Re --> emitter --> collector --> filter. If Re controls the emitter and collector current, would it determine the output impedance of the mixer?

Edit: Working frequencies are in the VHF range, IF is ~10 MHz.

Comment: No, that wouldn't work.

Comment: @Andyaka The mixer circuit wouldn't work or the impedance matching via Re wouldn't work? Operating passively I assumed the circuit would essentially be an unbalanced single diode mixer feeding into a bandpass filter